# Rails js.erb view doesn't get executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following

```
products_controller:

 def update


  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.update(product_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      format.js 
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Then I created a js file for that method y the views with a test code

```
views/products/update.js.erb:

    alert('product updated!');
```

Why it doesn't get executed?, some problem with turbolinks?

Comment: is it possible that your update failed, and you're in the 'else' branch?

Comment: js.erb is called through AJAX. Did you call it through standard web browser or through AJAX using Javascript ?

Comment: Can you add the rails log entries of what happens you reach this method.

Comment: How is the code used in the front-end? Did you get any error on the Rails log or the browser's console? What was the response did you get?